# Ubuntu 16.04 missing Network Printer options

Tags: networking, printing, protocol

I have a device on which Ubuntu 16.04 is running. When I want to add a new printer, I go to *Printers --> Select Device --> Network Printer* and choose the network printer I want. However, while I am sure I was able to add these printers before, I am not able anymore to add the following Network Printers:

- AppSocket/HP JetDirect
- Internet Printing Protocol (https)
- Internet Printing Protocol (ipp14)
- Internet Printing Protocol (ipp)
- Internet Printing Protocol (ipps)

These options do not appear anymore. I am able to manually add a printer with appSocket or ipp by typing a URI (for example: *socket://192.168.6.100:9100*), but when I print to these printers, the printjob is held in the print queue with the following status: *Processing - Not connected?*

When I try adding exactly the same printers with another device on which Ubuntu 16.04 is installed, I am able to print. I do not know which settings, updates or installations have caused this problem. Does anybody know what I can do to be able to print by AppSocket or IPP again?

Comment: Does your printer switched on? If your printer is from HP, you can try `hplip-gui` as well.

Comment: Yes, my printer is on. I could try hplip-gui, but that does not solve my problem. I am trying to get back my default network printer options.